# mongoosejs - find() using nested objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

question is possibly a duplicate but I haven't found anything that provides an appropriate answer to my issue.

I have an ExpressJS server which is used to provide API requests to retrieve data from a MongoDB database. I am using mongoosejs for the MongoDB connection to query/save data.

I am building a route that will allow me to find all data that matches some user input but I am having trouble when doing the query. I have spent a long while looking online for someone with a similar issue but coming up blank.

I will leave example of the code I have at the minute below.

**code for route**

```
// -- return matched data (GET)
router.get('/match', async (req, res) => {

    const style_data = req.query.style; // grab url param for style scores ** this comes in as a string **
    const character_data = req.query.character; // grab url param for character scores ** this comes in as a string **

    // run matcher systems
    const style_matches = style_match(style_data);

    res.send({
        response: 200,
        data: style_matches
    }); // return data

});
```

**code for the query**

```
// ---(Build the finder)
const fetch_matches_using = async function(body, richness, smoke, sweetness) {
    return await WhiskyModel.find({
        'attributes.body': body,
        'attributes.richness': richness,
        'attributes.smoke': smoke,
        'attributes.sweetness': sweetness
    });
}

// ---(Start match function)---

const style_match = async function (scores_as_string) {

    // ---(extract data)---
    const body = scores_as_string[0];
    const richness = scores_as_string[1];
    const smoke = scores_as_string[2];
    const sweetness = scores_as_string[3];

    const matched = [];

    // ---(initialise variables)---
    let match_count = matched.length;

    let first_run; // -> exact matches
    let second_run; // -> +- 1
    let third_run; // -> +- 2
    let fourth_run; // -> +- 3

    // ---(begin db find loop)---

    first_run = fetch_matches_using(body, richness, smoke, sweetness).then((result) => {return result});

    matched.push(first_run);

    // ---(return final data)---
    
    return matched

}
```

**example of db object**

```
{
 _id: mongoid,
 meta-data: {
  pagemd:{some data},
  name: whiskyname
  age: whiskyage,
  price: price
 },
 attributes: {
  body: "3",
  richness: "3",
  smoke: "0",
  sweetness: "3",
  some other data ...
 }
}
```

When I hit the route in postman the JSON data looks like:

```
{
response: 200,
data: {}
}
```

and when I console.log() out matched from within the style match function after I have pushed the it prints [ Promise(pending) ] which I don't understand.

if I console.log() the result from within the .then() I get an empty array.

I have tried using the populate() method after running the find which does technically work, but instead of only returning data that matches it returns every entry in the collection so I think I am doing something wrong there, but I also don't see why I would need to use the .populate() function to access the nested object.

Am I doing something totally wrong here?

I should also mention that the route and the matching functions are in different files just to try and keep things simple.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just posting an answer as I seem to have fixed this.

Issue was with my .find() function, needed to pass in the items to search by and then also a call back within the function to return error/data. I'll leave the changed code below.

**new function**

```
const fetch_matches_using = async function(body, richness, smoke, sweetness) {
    const data = await WhiskyModel.find({
        'attributes.body': body,
        'attributes.richness': richness,
        'attributes.smoke': smoke,
        'attributes.sweetness': sweetness
    }, (error, data) => { // new ¬
        if (error) { 
            return error;
        }

        if (data) {
            console.log(data)
            return data
        }
    });

    return data; //new
}
```

There is still an issue with sending the found results back to the route but this is a different issue I believe. If its connected I'll edit this answer with the fix for that.